# jQueryUI Slider embedded in Accordion fails bugs in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to add slider controls to accordion headers.

I've managed to mix the two together quite well using a the jQuery UI demos for both accordion and slider.

[**jsfiddle page**](http://jsfiddle.net/zeristor/wZzsw/).

> ```html
> <div id="accordion">
>   <div>
>     <h3>Section 1</h3>
>     <div class="slider" id="slider1"></div>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <p>Mauris mauris ante</p>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <h3>Section 2</h3>
>     <div class="slider" id="slider2"></div>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <p>Sed non urna.o.</p>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <h3>Section 3</h3>
>     <div class="slider" id="slider3">
>   </div>
> </div>
> <div>
>   <p>Nam enim risus.</p>
>   <ul>
>     <li>List item one</li>
>     <li>List item two</li>
>   </ul>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script>
>  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
>  $( ".slider" ).slider({
>   range: true,
>   min: 0,
>   max: 7,
>   values: [0, 7],
>   step: 0.5,
>   slide: function( event, ui ) {
>     var id=$(this).attr('id');
>     $( id).val( ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1] );
>
>     event.stopPropagation();
>   }   }); $( ".slider").mouseup();
>
> </script>
> ```

The problem is in moving a slider on an unopened accordion. Since the slider control snaps along the slide most of the time the user "mouseup"s away from slider button. This works as planned in Firefox [29.0.1], however in Chrome [35.0] a "mouseup" away from the slider button causes the accordion to open; undesired.

Closed accordion.
Move slider button.
Mouseup with cursor on slider button.

-> Slider moves accordion doesn't open **[PASS]**

Closed accordion.
Move slider button.
Mouseup with cursor OFF of slider button, but still on slider rule.

-> Slider moves accordion opens  **[FAIL]**

Closed accordion
Move slider button
Mouseup with cursor OFF out of accordion

-> Slider moves accordion doesn't open **[PASS]**

Since it is working for Firefox, but not for Chrome (and IE) I think this is probably a jQuery/jQuery-ui bug, I've learnt a fair bit taking this issue this far, I may be missing something obvious, is there a quick fix I can use to get around this? Or is this a chink in how jQuery papers over browser idiosyncracies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily disable the activation of a different tab of the accordion. The method is crude however, as it requires a timer and creates a tiny chance of a race condition.

First, create a flag that your accordion will evaluate:

```
var tempDisable = false;
```

Modify your accordion so it doesn't activate a different tab when the flag is set:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    beforeActivate: function() {
        if (tempDisable) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, on starting / stopping to drag a slider, set/unset the flag:

```js
    [...]
    start: function() {
        tempDisable = true;
    },
    stop: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            tempDisable = false;
        }, 10);
    }
    [...]
```

I've updated [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wZzsw/1/) with the fully working code. As stated above, this is not ideal because (as the `stop` event of the slider will occur before the `beforeActivate` of the panel) a timeout is required. I've set it to 10ms which should be a good balance between a CPU with high load and a very fast clicking user.